Mixing two strings with eachother
I have a program in which you get a random word, and you have to guess it by typing different letters, and it says if its in the word and in what place. But i can't seem to figure out how to overlap 2 strings with each other. For example, in my code this error keeps happening: You have the word: apple. And you guess the letter p. So you get as an output _pp__ and then you guess the letter l but instead of saying _ppl__ it just says _pp_____l_.
here is the code:
while True:
    Woord = input('Wat wil je dat het galgje woord wordt: ')
    correct = 0
    superCorrect = len(Woord)
    count = 0
    gokjes = 8
    dood = 0
    geraden_letters = ''
    letterNieuw = ''
    for i in range(20):
        print("")
    x = len(Woord)
    for i in range(x):
        print("_",end=' ')
    for i in range(2):
        print("")
    for i in range(gokjes):
        letter = input('Gok een letter: ')
        if letter == "":
            exit()
        else:
            if letter in Woord:
                count = Woord.count(letter)
                print('Correct')
                for char in Woord:
                    if char == letter:
                        geraden_letters += char
                        correct = correct + 1
                    else:
                        geraden_letters += '_'
                print(geraden_letters)
                if correct == superCorrect:
                    print('Het woord was ... ', geraden_letters.upper(),'!')
                    exit()
            else:
                print('Incorrect')
                print(letter)
                dood = 1
    if dood == 1:
        print('Het galgje is dood')
        print("")

tried the letter p, got output _pp___, then tried the letter l, expected output _ppl_, but got ___l_ instead.

Side note: some of the underscores in my question got erased because of stack overflow, so don't get confused

You should save the string _pp__ in the variable. Every time a letter is guessed correctly, you update that string.

Note that the code you're showing doesn't do what you describe: if you give it apple and guess p, it prints pp, then if you give it l, it prints ppl, then if you give it a, it prints ppla. There are no underscore placeholders, and guessed letters aren't ordered based on the original word's ordering right now.

Close to description now

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Output from that tio.run link I created by straight copy paste of OP's code, feeding it apple, p, l, and a as input was Gok een letter: Correct _pp__ Gok een letter: Correct _pp_____l_ Gok een letter: Correct _pp_____l_a____ Gok een letter:  Not exactly what's described, but close.

@Shadowranger, sure but the problem isn't that we don't know how to rewrite the code to do what is being claimed, the problem is that if you're posting a question, the code you're showing and the description of that code need to match. OP has a bit of work to do to make sure that they've written a good question.

OP also has to read formatting help and ensure what is displayed in the question is shown correctly.  "it got erased because of stack overflow", really means, "I don't know how to format correctly."

Does this answer your question? Python 3 hangman for a beginner

Initially trying out your code, I too was getting quirky results with underscores and letters, so I took a step back to attempt to replicate the spirit of your "Hangman" program.  Having seen many variations of the "Hangman" game I went the route of setting up a list to initially hold the same number of underscore characters as letters in the entered word/solution.  Then as guesses were made, the underscores in the list were replaced when a correct letter was guessed.
With that, following is a refactored version of your code keeping with spirit of your project.
Guess = []          # Use a list to contain the underscore and letters

while True:

    Woord = input('What do you want the hangman\'s word to be?: ')
    correct = 0
    superCorrect = len(Woord)
    for i in range(superCorrect):
        Guess.append('_')           # Create a list of underscores as long as the word
    count = 0
    gokjes = 8
    dood = 0
    
    for i in range(gokjes):
        letter = input('Guess a letter: ')
        if letter == "":
            exit()
        else:
            if letter in Woord:
                count = Woord.count(letter)
                print('Correct')
                for i in range(len(Woord)):
                    if Woord[i] == letter:
                        Guess[i] = letter       # Replace the underscore with the entered letter
                        correct = correct + 1

                if correct == superCorrect:
                    print('The word was ... ', Woord,'!')   # Just print the word if guessed correctly
                    exit()
            else:
                print('Incorrect')
                print(letter)
                dood = 1

        for i in range(len(Woord)):             # Print out the current list of characters
            print(Guess[i], end=' ')
        print()

    if dood == 1:
        print('The hangman is dead')
        print("")

The key points are as follows.

As noted, a list is initially set up to contain placeholder underscore characters.
As each correct letter guess is made, the underscore list value in the list is replaced with the guessed letter.
Feedback is then printed showing the user the progress of their guesses are.
If all correct letters are guessed, the user wins and the game ends; otherwise, the user loses.

Following was a test run showing the terminal output.
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Hangman$ python3 Beul.py 
What do you want the hangman's word to be?: apple
Guess a letter: p
Correct
_ p p _ _ 
Guess a letter: e
Correct
_ p p _ e 
Guess a letter: l
Correct
_ p p l e 
Guess a letter: a
Correct
The word was ...  apple !

Again, this is just one of many possible solutions, but this should provide food for thought.
